# Spring cloud kafka streams processor API kafka record key is null, while there is correct record value

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

```
    ...
    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Event receive(@Payload String record) {

            String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            Event event = composeEvent(); //generates an event
            return event;
    }
```

Since the @SendTo sends the returned event value directly to the OUTPUT Kafka topic destination, I cannot seem to find an example that sets key before the value is pushed to the output topic. The key turns out to be null in the kafka topic.

Any working code is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of s-c-stream you are using? 
Also, you are using a very outdated API. The annotation such as `@Input/@Output, @EnableBinding, @StreamListener etc` being deprecated. 
We have switched to a simpler [functional model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function). 

You can also read these two blog posts for additional context:
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive

Comment: Ok so in the new functional model, how do you read the record's topic name?

@StreamListener("input")
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<?, Event> process(KStream<Object, String> input) {

In the old version, you could do the following to read the record topic key:

@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Event receive(@Payload String record, @Header(MessageHeader.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName) {